# Why would a person be predisposed for joining an animal hive mind?

Tags: science-based, hive

Imagine a supercolony of bees (I'm using bees as a metaphor; they're not really bees) which are the constituents of a massive globe-spanning hive mind. The government wishes to exploit this supercolony for its own use: as a weapon to use against enemy forces, which would be a big help.

There's one problem, however. The bees can't be coordinated very easily with external stimuli. They have to be controlled internally, from the central intelligence of the hive. The government begins the search for a person who can be inducted into the hive.

**Why would a human be predisposed to joining a hive mind?** Preferably, the answer is simple, science-based, and plausible.

Comment: Simple. [Multiple personalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissociative_identity_disorder). Like... thousands of them. Too bad the govt will fail to control that human too. :grin:

Comment: People already know how the internet works, and 
from what modern science and common sense tells us humans are the only creature so far,  in the entire universe who can understand the abstract concept of an hive mind.

Comment: @Kyu `humans...  can understand the abstract concept of an hive mind.` I really doubt it. Understanding would have prevented spreading hoaxes, dumb memes, various forms of propaganda, a.s.o. and yet...

Comment: By understanding I mean that no other entity knows what even a hive mind is to begin with. At least I'm pretty sure geese, cows or other animals don't spend their time wondering what is like sharing a brain with other individuals.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi but [MEMES is the DNA of the SOUL](https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/902/970/98b.jpg)!!

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Hive minds wouldn't necessarily prevent idiotic behavior. Look at the behavior of modern eusocial species like ants, bees, termites, and naked mole rats. These are not happy utopian societies, individuals try and cheat the system all the time. E.g., workers ants will try to lay eggs unless attacked and beaten by other workers. Natural selection will favor individuals who exploit the hive mind at the expense of everyone else unless suppressed (because from a fitness perspective they gain from it more than others do), as it does with every hypersocial species.

Comment: One main problem with the using a human to control the bees is that if that, at least for normal bees, if they're being controlled by something, that means the hive has a queen, which uses special pheromones to issue commands. So yeah, you'll need a human who can somehow be accepted as a queen (after the current one is killed, obviously) and have access to (either by producing them naturally or via sprays) the pheromones necessary to order the hive around.

Comment: @ProjectApex I was using bees as a real-world comparison to the things in my world, so my apologies for the confusion : )

Comment: @pg4919 it's np, but do be aware of this though. A hive mind  community usually indicates a hive leader controlling it, one you'll need to get rid of before putting your human there. Additionally, your human will need to have knowledge over the means of communication the hive leader uses to issue orders, be it pheromones, telepathic signals or other means. Just a heads up for these issues regarding conventional hive mind communities : ).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**He is a weird kid.**

He is different, and weird, and crushingly lonely.  He was born different and weird but he is still little and so people give him the benefit of the doubt.  He wants to connect with others and he tries hard but he cannot make it happen to his satisfaction.  He feels isolated and lonely and struggles to communicate this feeling.

His parents thought he might be autistic.  He is not.  He is something else.  His mind craves a closeness and connection that is not possible with human biology - we are each stranded in the lonely island that is our body, calling out to the other islands across the void.

In the hive mind, he finally finds the connection that he craves.  And there is much, much more to the planetary hive mind than the government realizes.  It is not just bees.

Comment: Dun Dunn Dunnnn... honesty seems like something that could actually happen

Comment: Nice answer. It fits in with the plot really well, too.

Comment: Turn of the plot: the weird kid learns from the hive mind the govt is evil and turns the "weapon" on it. Unexpected? No, otherwise there's no tension in the plot.

Comment: Real turn of the plot: kid has larger interests that hopefully are in alignment with those of humankind.  When you merge a human with a planetary mind millions of years old, you have created a god.

Comment: Real, real turn of the plot: the hive mind is neither entirely good nor entirely bad, and once it's started figuring out humans and politics, it becomes an actor on the world stage, equal with nations, with it's own unique interests.  Political maneuverings by all ensue.  Except that would be really hard to write well.

Comment: Oh No! its [Not just The Bees!!!](https://media.tenor.com/images/51c94be74a756b62931ad229ccfa6270/tenor.gif)

Comment: The kid has to be called Buzz. This much is certain.